# floating point representation in memory is just not clear for me

Tags: c++, c, memory, floating-point

My task was to **get the fraction of a float then store it in an int.**
It seemed very easy. I did this test:

```
float f = 3.1415f;
printf("int pres. of float: %d\n"
       "int:                %d", *((int *)&f), 31415);
```

output:

`int pres. of float: 1078529622`

`int: 31415`

I changed them to base 2 to see where the 31415 is present.

```
0100 0000 0100 1001 0000 1110 0101 0110 - 3.1415
                    0111 1010 1011 0111 - 31415
```

I don't know what to do. How could I get the fraction as a simple integer?

Comment: A mantissa is the fraction bit!

Comment: sorry, i correct it to be more clear

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to understand the binary representation of floating point numbers?

Comment: How about (f-3) * 10000 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take 2.5, instead of 3.1415, because it's fairly easy to understand...

So your assumption is that 2.5 and 25 should have the same binary format. This is not the case. 25 = 0x19 = 11001. 2.5 = 10.1. Not at all the same thing.

If you feel like doing the same sort of math for 3.1415, it goes something like this:

```
3      = 11 (I can do that)
1/8    = 0.001  
0.1415 - 0.125 = 0.0165
1/64   = 0.000001
0.0165 - 0.015625 = 0.000875
1/2048 = 0.00000000001
```

And we still have some fractions of 0.1415 left to deal with at this point, but a rough result 11.00100100001.

Now, if we compare your binary output (starting at the mantissa part), and inserting a decimal point, and take into account that floating point numbers "ignore the first one":

```
  11.00100100001
   1.00100100001110
```

Seems like my scribbles above aren't completely off... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Guess you need to start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point. This will tell you about the various representations of floating point numbers

Comment: I thought in a float32 there's an int23 for storing the value without the decimal point. So i was wrong.

Comment: @BálintJuhász: Close: There's an int23 for storing the value without the _ binary_  point. Computers don't work in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

There are two key complications. One is that float is a binary floating point type, so it cannot represent 3.1415f exactly. All you have is an approximation. The closest exactly representable float value is 3.141499996185302734375.

The other is that 3.1415f is in the range of normalized numbers, which means the most significant bit of the significand, if stored, would be a non-zero binary digit, so it is not stored.